# How to use margins package to evaluate marginal affects at different values of the dependent variable

Tags: r, marginal-effects

I am using the `margins` package ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#Using_the_at_Argument)) to well, calculate margins, with respect to an ordinal variable. The margins package is an attempt to "port the functionality of Stata’s (closed source) margins". [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9kvqeLFF8U) (around 4:25) shows that for an ordinal probit model in Stata, I can evaluate the marginal effect of a variable at different values of the ordinal variable, in my example `x2`.

I tried `polr_1st_margins <- summary(margins(fit.polr, at = list(x2= 2:4)))` and this works on the example data. For some weird reason, when I run it on my actual data I get an error. In both cases `x2` is a factor variable (otherwise `polr` won't run).

I get the error: `Error in dat[, not_numeric, drop = FALSE] :  incorrect number of dimensions` even when the variable is there.

Does someone have an idea what could be going on?

Example code:

```
library(sure) # for residual function and sample data sets
library(MASS) # for polr function
library(margins)
rm(df1)
df1 <- df1
df1$x2 <- df2$y
df1$x3 <- df2$x
df1$y <- df3$x/10
fit.polr <- polr(x2 ~ x + x3, data = df1, method = "probit")
summary(margins(fit.polr))

polr_1st_margins <- summary(margins(fit.polr, at = list(x2= 2:4)))
```

## EDIT

I have decided to add a sample of my actual code (also posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/leeper/margins/issues/169)).

```
fit.polr2 <- polr(ordinal_dep_var ~ Dummy + Continuous + Dummy2 + as.factor(industry) + Urbanisation_Dummy + Size_Dummy, data = df2, method = "probit", Hess=TRUE)
summary(margins(fit.polr2))

polr_1st_margins <- summary(margins(fit.polr2, at = list(ordinal_dep_var= 0:3)))

Error in dat[, not_numeric, drop = FALSE] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Somehow, it does not find the variable, even though I can see that it is there.

## DATA

```
df2 <- structure(list(ordinal_dep_var = structure(c(4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Dummy = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Continuous = c(15.6862745098039, 
41.6666666666667, 26.9230769230769, 14.8514851485149, 32.1428571428571, 
20, 43.75, 0, 0, 0, 80, 100, 21.4285714285714, 23.8095238095238, 
28.125, 0, 30.3030303030303, 25, 100, 100, 100, 13.3333333333333, 
66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 55.5555555555556, 72.2222222222222, 
57.3033707865169, 17.7777777777778, 47.6190476190476, 17.7777777777778, 
41.6666666666667, 40, 20, 8.33333333333333, 16.6666666666667, 
40, 100, 0, 50, 0, 0, 7.69230769230769, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
33.3333333333333, 20, 1.84089414858646, 1.84089414858646, 1.84089414858646, 
30, 20, 0, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 100, 
50, 22.2222222222222, 0, 0, 50, 50, 46.1538461538462, 44.4444444444444, 
0, 5.55555555555556, 0, 0, 47.3684210526316, 43.75, 18.1818181818182, 
0, 42.8571428571429, 14.2857142857143, 0, 50, 0, 0, 50, 20, 50, 
100, 0, 42.8571428571429, 20, 25, 33.3333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 
66.6666666666667, 0, 25.9259259259259, 0, 33.3333333333333, 0, 
100, 25, 0, 0, 10, 100, 50, 33.3333333333333, 75, 0, 0, 40, 0, 
33.3333333333333, 28.5714285714286, 0, 0, 28.5714285714286, 0, 
28.5714285714286, 0, 0, 9.09090909090909, 30, 66.6666666666667, 
50, 0, 20, 50, 0, 33.3333333333333, 0, 66.6666666666667, 18.1818181818182, 
28.5714285714286, 36.9230769230769, 14.2857142857143, 36.3636363636364, 
0, 0, 7.69230769230769), Dummy2 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), label = "Gift/informal payment requested: tax inspectorate?", format.stata = "%14.0f", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Yes = 1, No = 2)), industry = structure(c(3, 
7, 2, 7, 19, 17, 9, 7, 9, 11, 12, 10, 5, 5, 3, 12, 3, 5, 4, 1, 
1, 11, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 5, 9, 4, 7, 9, 11, 11, 22, 12, 21, 19, 
11, 10, 7, 19, 23, 20, 20, 21, 24, 19, 1, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 6, 6, 21, 3, 17, 19, 20, 12, 21, 20, 12, 10, 10, 21, 21, 
19, 3, 21, 21, 10, 10, 21, 5, 20, 21, 19, 22, 15, 6, 21, 21, 
10, 19, 21, 20, 3, 6, 10, 24, 24, 21, 23, 21, 21, 11, 21, 3, 
3, 21, 24, 21, 1, 10, 22, 19, 17, 3, 20, 23, 1, 22, 21, 21, 23, 
21, 23, 21, 22, 22, 21, 10, 13, 10, 15, 10, 24, 24, 7, 10, 10, 
22, 21, 21, 23, 21, 22, 7, 21), label = "Industry", format.stata = "%34.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Textiles = 1, Leather = 2, 
Garments = 3, Agroindustry = 4, Food = 5, Beverages = 6, `Metals and machinery` = 7, 
Electronics = 8, `Chemicals and pharmaceutics` = 9, Construction = 10, 
`Wood and furniture` = 11, `Non-metallic and plastic materials` = 12, 
Paper = 13, `Sport goods` = 14, `IT services` = 15, `Other manufacturing` = 16, 
Telecommunications = 17, `Accounting and finance` = 18, `Advertising and marketing` = 19, 
`Other services` = 20, `Retail and wholesale trade` = 21, `Hotels and restaurants` = 22, 
Transport = 23, `Real estate and rental services` = 24, `Mining and quarrying` = 25, 
`Auto and auto components` = 26, `Other transport equipment` = 27, 
`Other unclassified` = 99)), Urbanisation_Dummy = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("City > 250", 
"50k-250k", "< 50k"), class = "factor"), Size_Dummy = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Employees: < 10", 
"Employees: 10-19", "Employees: 20+"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Removed the Stata tag. The history of this code as emulating Stata code has no bearing on the question or likely answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is a bug in the `margins` code for `polr` models.
You might want to try [the `marginaleffects` package
instead.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/)
(Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

```r
library(MASS)
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- polr(factor(gear) ~ hp, data = mtcars, method = "probit")

mfx <- marginaleffects(mod, type = "probs")

summary(mfx)
```

```
## Average marginal effects 
##    type Group Term     Effect Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)     2.5 %    97.5 %
## 1 probs     3   hp  0.0009916  0.0011329  0.8753  0.38142 -0.001229 0.0032122
## 2 probs     4   hp -0.0003951  0.0004637 -0.8521  0.39415 -0.001304 0.0005137
## 3 probs     5   hp -0.0005965  0.0007168 -0.8322  0.40530 -0.002001 0.0008084
## 
## Model type:  polr 
## Prediction type:  probs
```